# Given that the Fourier coefficients of the function prove that the function is continuous

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Here is the problem:

Given that the Fourier coefficients of the function $f(x)$ are:
$a_n=0$ , $b_n= \frac{1}{n!}$

1. Prove or disprove that $f(x)$ is continuous
2. Find the function explicitly
3. What are the Fourier coefficients of $f'(x)$

Comment: For part 1, you need to show that the Fourier Series for $f$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Can you expand it for me

Comment: Weierstrass M-Test